# Set oracle standard data type for varchar2 from BYTE to CHAR

Tags: sql, oracle, sqldatatypes

Data type varchar2 can be stored as BYTE or CHAR. If in DDL it's not defined as which, it create automatically as BYTE. This can cause problems since some characters are bigger than one byte. So basically 1 byte is not always equal 1 char. I could not find where to change the default setting for varchar2 data type to CHAR instead of BYTE.

So basically i want define DDL as
`CREATE TABLE TBL1 (COLUMN1 VARCHAR2(100))` 
and get TBL1 with column1 as varchar2(100 CHAR) and not varchar2(100 BYTE)

Comment: `your_field_name VARCHAR2(100 CHAR)` (`100` just in the example...)

Comment: I want that oracle automatically create the table with varchar(100 char) when i enter create table tbl1 ( column1 varchar2(100) )

Comment: You need to set it in the Oracle parameter `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the default using:

```
alter system set NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS=CHAR
```

If you want to change it at session level you can use:

```
alter session set NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS=CHAR
```

from [oracle-base](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/character-semantics-and-globalization-9i).

It's probably safest to set the parameter for the session instead of the instance. According to the [Database Reference entry for NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS.html):

> Oracle strongly recommends that you do NOT set the
> NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS parameter to CHAR in the instance or server
> parameter file. This may cause many existing installation scripts to
> unexpectedly create columns with character length semantics, resulting
> in run-time errors, including buffer overflows.

Comment: "Documentation" refers only to the documents published and maintained by Oracle itself; link provided below. **oracle-base.com** is maintained by an Oracle expert who does not work for Oracle; his work (which is always excellent!) is not "documentation". I provide a link to the actual documentation below, to give access to the full syntax; the OP - or anyone else interested in this - may want to pay close attention to the **SCOPE** clause of `alter sytem` (so that they only need to make the change once, rather that every time the db is restarted).

Comment: Link to documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_2017.htm#CCHFDBIF

Comment: Thanks @mathguy to complete the answer, maybe the "documentation" word was not correct, I just wanted to link the place where I got the information.